# How To Set Up Tracking Pixel on External Lead Form

Tags: matomo

I am currently using Piwik and Clicky on one of my websites. Right now I track visitors who enter their zip code and click on one of my outgoing advertising links. However, I will be implementing an external pop up lead form to gather data (name, address, zip code,age, email, etc.) for advertising.  I know that I can track who visits the zip code form using Piwik or Clicky, but I have no idea how to set up a tracking pixel for the lead form.

The only documentation I could find that I think can be used for piwik points me to this [page](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/#toc-two-tracking-methods-image-tracking-or-using-the-api.)    My guess is I need to incorporate the Advanced Image Tracker. I didn't find anything I could use for Clicky.

An example of the lead form can be found [here](https://www.healthplansamerica.org/insurance/cheaphealthinsr/index.php?Referrer=JS&Subreferrer=CHI&zip=77449&Go.x=0&Go.y=0)

Would somebody be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

I'm hoping that there is a way to use either software to get this done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal Piwik tracking pixel should work, something like the below

`<img src="http://localhost/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1&amp;rec=1" style="border:0" alt="" />`

you can also get creative with adding custom variables and more. details here: 
http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/reference/#toc-tracking-api-endpoint

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the late reply.  I didn't see the response until now.